# run postgraphile with npm

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, npm-run, postgraphql

I'm working on a react app and using apollo and postgraphile for graphql. I currently have to have two terminal windows open, one running

```
npm start
```

for the react-dev server, and one running

```
postgraphile -c 'postgresstring'
```

for the postgraphile server

everything works when doing this, but i'm passing the project off to the rest of my team and would like them to be able to simply run

```
npm start
```

to start both the react and postgraphile servers. I tried using the npm packages concurrently and npm-start-all to run both scripts on npm start, but every time i use npm to run the postgraphile command I get errors on trying to actually query the graphql server in graphiql saying that i have duplicate instances of graphql running. this happens even if i put the postgraphile command in it's own npm command like

```
"graphql": "postgraphile -c 'postgresstring'"
```

and run

```
npm run graphql
```

error message:

```
Error: Cannot use GraphQLSchema "[object Object]" from another module or realm.

Ensure that there is only one instance of "graphql" in the node_modules
directory. If different versions of "graphql" are the dependencies of 
other relied on modules, use "resolutions" to ensure only one version 
is installed.

https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions

Duplicate "graphql" modules cannot be used at the same time since different
versions may have different capabilities and behavior. The data from one
version used in the function from another could produce confusing and
spurious results.
```

How can I run postgraphile via npm run so that i can use concurrently or npm-run-all to run both of them with a single command? note that simply using "node scripts/start.js && postgraphile -c 'postgresstring'" won't work because it waits for the start.js server to terminate before running postgraphile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common pain for people working with `graphql` in the Node.js ecosystem. The way to solve this is to add a `"resolutions"` entry to your `package.json` informing yarn that it should try and install just one version, `graphql@0.12.x`, anywhere that version satisfies the supported GraphQL ranges rather than installing multiple versions. To do so, add something like this to your `package.json` file:

```
"resolutions": {
  "graphql": "0.12.x"
}
```

Then run `yarn` again and you should notice that your `yarn.lock` file has been updated to only reference one version of `graphql`.

---

#### Explanation

The first `postgraphile` command you're running executes the globally installed `postgraphile` command (installed via `npm install -g postgraphile` or `yarn global add postgraphile`); which doesn't suffer this issue because it has only its own dependencies and they don't conflict.

However for the `npm run` command, npm automatically adds your local `./node_modules/.bin/` folder to the beginning of `$PATH` and thus your local copy of `postgraphile` (installed via `yarn add postgraphile`) is being executed instead. (This is the behaviour you want!) It seems you've also installed something else that depends on `graphql` (perhaps Apollo Client?) and you now have two versions of `graphql` somewhere in your `node_modules` folder, each in different locations, and `postgraphile` is picking up a different version to `graphile-build`, which is causing the issue.

Happy PostGraphiling!

Comment: Update: current advice is to use `graphql@0.13.x` as the resolution target.

Comment: I know comments aren't for saying thanks, but I really feel start struck by this answer, and really wanted to thank you for not only answering, but also providing such a thorough explanation that really helped me to understand the problem I was having instead of just knowing how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, your feedback is appreciated 